# Do blueberry seeds germinate when submerged in water?

Tags: seeds, germination, blueberries

There are some videos that appear to show blueberry seeds germinating in nothing but water, for example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lpHXa66fc9E. I cannot find any information on this outside YouTube, in particular nothing in writing.

**Question**: Does this actually work? If yes, what is the precise procedure?

Comment: I see 3 weeks of soaking in bottled water. Then moving to soil. It may not be a hoax, but nothing in writing tells you something, too.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this with blueberry seeds of 3 different origins - it did not work.

Comment: Hi and thanks for sharing your experiment! I am guessing that you are the same person as the asker? If yes, you can request that your accounts get merged. Find the instructions [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).